# Change time display format python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

I am able to get the current time using the below code

```
import datetime
current_time = print(datetime.datetime.now())
Output : 2018-04-30 14:09:58.483829
```

I would however like to remove the decimal portion and only display 2018-04-30 14:09:58. How could I get this value. Thanks..

Comment: nice dupe find!! and nice python 3 gold :)

Comment: Thanks Kasramvd..